# Check if there exists a Folder with a specific Name in a Parent Folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to create a new folder within a parent folder, but only if it does not exist already.

I created a function that checks whether there exists a folder named "folder_name" within a parent_folder. I want it to return `false` in case there is no folder with "folder_name" within parent_folder, so I later can use in an if statement.

```
function checkFolder(parent_folder, folder_name) {
  var folders_in_parent = parent_folder.getFolders();
  while (folders_in_parent.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders_in_parent.next();
    if(folder_name == folder.getName()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that parameter "parent_folder" is not a folder name, but the folder itself that I get using the folder ID:

```
var parentFolderID = "ID_goes_here";
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID);
```

Then, I use the checkFolder function to check whether the new folder exists or not; if it does not, I create it:

```
var newFoldercheck = checkFolder(parentFolder,"New Folder");
 
if (newFoldercheck === false) {
  var newFolder = campusFolder.createFolder("New Folder");
}
```

Every time I run my script, it always creates the New Folder, even if it already exists in the parent folder. Please, could you help me identify what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe you should add to your code what values do the variables `campusFolder` and `maincoursefoldersFolderName` have.

Comment: @ Nightloewe thanks! done!

Comment: I think that your current script works. For example, I'm worry whether your folder names retrieved by `getFolders()` has the spaces for 1st and last of name. So when `if(folder_name == folder.getName()) {` is modified to `if(folder_name.trim() == folder.getName().trim()) {`, what result will you get? Or, as a simple script, how about `function checkFolder(parent_folder,folder_name){return parent_folder.getFoldersByName(folder_name.trim()).hasNext() ? true : false}`? I post it as a comment because I'm not sure about your actual situation.

Comment: I assume that `parentFolder` and `campusFolder` refer to the same folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better to do the comparison like this.  I think it gives you a better chance to find matches that look alike but are not exactly alike.

```
function checkFolder(parent_folder, folder_name) {
  var folders_in_parent=parent_folder.getFolders();
  while (folders_in_parent.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders_in_parent.next();
    if(folder_name.trim() == folder.getName().trim()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```